# rebuild tree in Winedt once open a tex file

Tags: winedt

How to automatically rebuild tree panel once a tex file is opened in Winedt?

I tries and put

BuildTree;TreeSelectBranch('TOC');TreeAutoSelect(1,'TOC',1,2,0,2);

in the "Open Document (After)", but it does not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because this event handler is not enabled in default WinEdt settings.

In `Events.ini` you'll find:

```
// The following are not used by default (faster!):
// Remove the comment to enable any of these handlers!
//ON_DOC_OPEN_AFTER="%b\Macros\Events\MDIOpen.edt"
//ON_DOC_ACTIVATE="%b\Macros\Events\MDIActivate.edt"
//ON_DOC_SAVE="%b\Macros\Events\MDISave.edt"
```

Now you know what to do.